# Создание нескольких таблиц с одной и той же связью один-к-одному

Tags: sql, postgresql

Возник вопрос, требуется создать бд, в которой есть три группы пользователей (ясное дело, что у всех у них будет одна таблица(*?или лучше не стоит так делать?*), содержащую данные об аккаунте - а именно логин, хэш пароля и роль), однако, на практике все эти три таблицы, будут иметь разные связи с другими таблицами и иметь разный набор полей (поэтому кидать три группы пользователей в одну таблицу - не вариант)

Если я создам три такие таблицы, то при занесении новой записи, придется проверять на уникальность сразу по трём таблицам, чтобы не занести повторяющийся телефон или почту.

У меня есть пара вариантов, но думаю, что есть выход легче и так.

**1)** Перенести все возможно повторяющиеся поля (телефон, почта) в таблицу аккаунты. И все равно придется проверять то, чтобы в таблице (например) разработчиков и менеджеров не выступало одно и то же значение первичного ключа **<Логин>**
**2)** Оставить всё как есть и только проверять на уникальность поле **<Логин>**
**3)** Начал сходить с ума, хотел все отличающиеся поля закинуть в JSONB
**4)** Или помучить многие-ко-многим
[image: Пример]
Не судите строго, если ответ на поверхности, я работаю уже третьи сутки, туплю дико :)
Появилась такая идея - создать общую базу аккаунтов, выделить три поля и по выбору выставлять внешний ключ на менеджера, если менеджер, соответсвенно, а другие поля пропускать, хотя мне кажется все равно, чушь....
[image: Появилась еще вот такая идея]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю такой вариант:

1. Вся инфа о всех юзерах в одной таблице.
2. Во второй таблице - роли этих юзеров. Т.е. таблица вида: `id, user_id, role`

Так у вас и данные о юзерах в одной таблице и роли можно легко добавлять/удалять.

Comment: А как тогда контролировать отличимые поля, к примеру у клиентов будет внешний ключ на Физическое и Юридическое лица, у остальных двух групп, этих полей не будет?, конечно можно установить двум другим группам значение <отсутствует> на это поле, как вариант, при условии что поле будет NOT NULL

Comment: По идее можно отдельные таблицы для физиков и юриков и, соответственно, также отдельные таблицы соединения юзеров с физиками и юриками, аналогично соединительной таблице для ролей.

Answer (score 0):

```
предлагаю так:
5 таблиц
таблица 1 [Люди] (согласна с первым ответом) - вся информация о юзерах:        
     Имя
     Фамилия
     Отчество
     Телефон
     Почта
     Логин
     hash_Пароль
     ID_роль int (по умолчанию id самого низкого типа доступа - клиента 
                          из таблицы 2)
     ID_предприятия int, может быть пустым (для юридических лиц, id из таблицы 5)

таблица 2 [роль] (опять же, - согласна с первым ответом)
     название (разработчик, менеджер, клиент)

таблица 3 [тип клиента]
     название (физическое лицо, представляет юридическое лицо)

таблица 4 [люди как клиенты]  эта таблица нужна, т.к. один и тот же человек 
                              может быть представителем юр.лица и, в то же время,
                              являться клиентом как физ.лицо
     ID_люди (из таблицы 1)
     ID_тип клиента  (из таблицы 3)

таблица 5 [предприятия] в этой таблице могут быть данные о реквизитах юр.лица 
                             и прочая информация
     название_предприятия
     реквизиты...
```